# Table name and column name are same in mvc model class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

i create a mode class in mvc just like

```
public class emp
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string emp { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Telefono { get; set; }

    public short ProveedorID { get; set; }
    public Proveedor Proveedor { get; set; }

    public short UsuarioID { get; set; }
    public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

My model name and one of the column name are emp
have any solution change moel with out effecting my table?

Comment: The answer would relate to how you have the rest of your project setup. More info needed. But you can change model name to be different to table name depending on any ORMs you are using

Comment: i am using ADO.NET Entity Framework

Comment: Are you using code first or database first?

Comment: i use database first

Comment: i have no permission for change database table

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
 public class emp
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Column("emp")]
        public string employee { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }

        public short ProveedorID { get; set; }
        public Proveedor Proveedor { get; set; }

        public short UsuarioID { get; set; }
        public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using database first and entity framework then I'm guessing you have an edmx file that does all the mapping of tables to classes, you should be able to change which class is used in there. I'd just try changing the class name and go from there